# How to add connection string in Config File in WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, connection-string

I am a beginner and learning WPF Application. I have a simple project and in that I want to read DB Configuration string from App.Config File. But I am not able to do so. Below is my attempt:

**APP.Config File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=Connect;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**CS Code:**

```
    public static void GetDataFromDB()
            {
                //var CS = @"Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=Connect;Integrated Security=SSPI";
               // ABOVE CODE WORKS FINE
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblTenant", con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
```

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Comment: You may want to change the elements in your config to capital letters. It might be case sensitive.. Not sure.

Comment: I have a ASP.Net web project their I have EXACT same settings and it works fine. :-|. Only difference there I have added this in web.config file.

Comment: Kindly see my edit. I have added the solution explorer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the connnection string in the `App.config` of the running WPF application and not in the DAL or any other class library.

The `ConfigurationManager` class reads the configuration file of the running executable.

Answer (score 0):

Add "clear" to your app.config before the connections string definition. It will look like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=Connect;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Still a null reference, or a different error? I put the same thing into a WPF application and it was fine. Presumably your configuration manager is System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager? Also, if you look at the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings collection, is it empty? In my code, I reference the collection by index, not name, i.e. ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString (But actually, both work).

Comment: I did silly mistake. Actually my app.config file was in different project which was added as a class library. Sorry for the confusion. I am a beginner so I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in the App.config:

Comment: Try than in the App.config to replace with: <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=Connect;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

You can add Connection string to both DAL and UI projects.

Try removing Data Source =.\ to Data Source =.